# How can I upgrade spreadACtions.none in spreadjs 10?

Tags: gspread, spreadjs

I am upgrading spreadjs 8 to 10.
By the way I cannot upgrade this line.

```
            sheet.addKeyMap(GC.Spread.Sheets.Key.del, false, false, false, false, GC.Spread.Sheets.SpreadActions.none);
```

I think this is delete disable function.
How can I upgrade this line?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah looks like that particular function was in v9 but removed in v10, and they don't seem to have added an equivalent going by this table...

http://help.grapecity.com/spread/SpreadSheets10/webframe.html#APIWSChanges.html

Comment: I imagine that if there was an alternate v10 method they would have listed it on that page, like they've done for the other ones. Best thing to do would be to email their support dept and ask them directly or ask a question in their discussion forum.